# Trying to code a grid using HTML and CSS similar to this

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-grid

I am trying to make a grid where different majors are listed, similar to this but instead of 4 columns, I want 3...
[grid similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGZAt.png)

So far I'm trying to work with this but the padding is really off because each button needs different padding according to the size of the word inside. So using this code the output looks like this... (ps. bootstrap is linked so there is no problem with that)

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>


<body style="background-color:white">
   <!-- heading -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="tab">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button1')">Accounting and Information Systems</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button2')">African Studies</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button3')">American Indian Studies</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button1')">Anthropology</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button2')">Art</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button3')">Asian American Studies</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[output of the HTML provided above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW7Ul.png)

Comment: please provide working code.

Comment: You will want to build this as a table, not divs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of class in `<div clas="col">`

You may want to consider using a [html table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) as it is designed for what you want to do in this scenario and the cells will not wrap when you reduce the screen width.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below `HTML` and `CSS` to make a grid.You can also give padding and other css to every column with style hope it will work.

> HTML

```
  <div class="srow">
        <div class="scol">
         <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button2')">Accounting and Information Systems</button>
        </div>
        <div class="scol">
         <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button3')">African Studies</button>
        </div>
        <div class="scol">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button1')">American Indian Studies</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="srow">
        <div class="scol">
         <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button2')">Anthropology</button>
        </div>
        <div class="scol">
         <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button3')">Art</button>
        </div>
        <div class="scol">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button1')">Asian American Studies</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> CSS

```
.srow{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.scol{
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use a table, it's best suited for this sort of tabular data. The only drawback to it is responsiveness on mobiles, but you can put it in a div that is set to overflow-x hidden at a certain width, then the user can swipe/scroll to see all the data.

```css
  table tr td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: .25em;
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  }
  
  a {
  color: #2d2d2d;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Accounting and Information Systems</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Civic and Community Engagement</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Health Sciences</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Physical Therapy</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have added some css and `button` tag change into `a` tag.

```css
.tab .col {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.tablinks {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="tab">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <a class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button1')">Accounting and Information Systems</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <a class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button2')">African Studies</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <a class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button3')">American Indian Studies</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <a class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button1')">Anthropology</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <a class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button2')">Art</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <a class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Button3')">Asian American Studies</a>
  </div>
</div>
```